# Handlebars - Render attributes

Tags: templates, handlebars.js

I'm currently having a problem rendering attributes like style="top:10%" with my handlebars template. My Template looks something like this

```
{{#each items}}
<a href="#" class="item" style="left:{{position}}">
</a>
{{/each}}
```

When I console my models they have the attribute of position and it's set to '10%'. But I don't seem to get anything.

Instead I get

```
<a href="#" class="item" style="left:">
</a>
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok solved it. This does work. Was looking at the wrong page. But it's probably best to use {{{position}}}